# How To Retrieve the Second to Last Row of the Provided ID

Tags: laravel

How can I retrieve the second to last row of the id provided?

```php
public function show($id)
{
    if (! Gate::allows('backup_view')) {
        return abort(401);
    }
    $backup = Backup::findOrFail($id);
    $second = Backup::select('id')->union($backup)->where('id', '<=' , $backup->id);
    dd($second); 

    return view('admin.backups.show', compact('backup', 'secondlast'));
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to return the variable $second. You are returning a variable called 'secondlast'. Try changing the name of the variable to $secondlast.

Answer (score 0):

In order to return the second last record from the Backup Model, the following query should work assuming your primary key is 'id':

```
Backup::orderBy('id', 'desc')
->skip(1)
->take(1)
->first();
```